# VS Code Python debugger would not start with Python extension 2022.Xx.xx although latest 2021 (2021.12.1559732655) works. Starting regular run works

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When starting a python script in debug mode from VS code nothing happens. I do not see any command being lunched in terminal.
If I start the script without debugging it starts fine.

I read on another thread somewhere that choosing an older Python extension like 2021.12.1559732655 would fix it and indeed it does but I would like to use the latest version of Python extension.

Anyone has any idea what broke in the new extensions starting with 2022.. basically anything with 2022 will not do anything when attempting to start the script in debug.

I am running remotely from a windows using ssh on a centos7 with python 2.7 and python 3.6. Not sure if that matters.

I tried starting python scripts from Visual Studio code in debug mode
VS code does  not do anything.

Tried modifying the config , restart , switching back to python 2.7 without  result..

The only thing that works is reverting to a version pre 2022

Comment: This is not a common problem or a problem that can be replicated. Maybe it is a better solution to ask developers in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I got my answer on ghithub. The debugger will not work with versions lower than Python 3.7.

For anything other than Python 3.7+ (like Python 2.6 )  use the 2021.12 version of the vs code  python extension.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19559#issuecomment-1358494296

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio Code:

> Version: 1.86.2 (user setup)
>
> Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
>
> Date: 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z
>
> Electron: 27.2.3
>
> ElectronBuildId: 26908389
>
> Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
>
> Node.js: 18.17.1
>
> V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
>
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

I solved this issue by creating a "launch.json" file in a ".vscode" folder, in the project folder (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).
Without this file, the debugger didn't start. Using previous versions of VS Code, I was able to start a debugger without "launch.json" file, but not now.
After creating the file, the python debugger started ok.