# vscode changing python interpreter leads to no module named debugpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-extensions

Since I changed the python interpreter from the default one in my system, I am no longer able to debug python code.
When I hit F5, I see a loading bar in the "RUN and DEBUG" window, it loads for a few seconds then disappears and nothing more.

My vscode

> Version: 1.75.1 (user setup)
> Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
> Date: 2023-02-08T21:32:34.589Z
> Electron: 19.1.9
> Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
> Node.js: 16.14.2
> V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
> Sandboxed: No

Default python interpreter `3.6.8` , new one that I am trying `3.10.2`

Note that I am using vscode server on a rhel8 from win10.
I tried with 2 different version of the python extension: `2022.8.1` and `2023.2.0`

I also tried launching it from command line and I got:
`No module named debugpy`

From my understanding debugpy is included in the python extension, apparently after changing the interpreter it can not be found anymore?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: there is no Python 3.20...

Comment: Can't edit right now, but yes that's a typo: 3.10.2

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19441

> `debugpy` dropped support for python 3.6 (since it is out of service for about 6 months now). Please pin to 2022.08.* version of the extension which was the last version with 3.6 support.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74998617/19133920

> For anything other than Python 3.7+ (like Python 2.6 ) use the 2021.12 version of the vs code python extension.

If you use python3.7 and later versions there will be no problem. If you use python3.6, you may need to install the corresponding python extension version. Roll back the version to 2022.8.* or earlier version to adapt to your python version.

Comment: Thank you Jiale, I was aware of this and I am able to debug with py 3.6.8 and ext 2022.08
My problem is that I can not debug py 3.10.2

Comment: Sorry you didn't make that clear in your question. Try installing `debugpy` for your interpreter. `/path/to/new/python/interpreter -m pip install debugpy`

Comment: I happen to have the same issue, but manually installing debugpy to my new interpreter did not solve this. Even if the debugpy version in both interpreters is the same